# "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown)"

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I'm in the last steps of my task manager app: getting the tasks to sync between devices. However, I get the error "This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown).  It cannot perform a save operation." What does this error exactly mean? My container is initialised so it should have a persistent store, right? I've also enabled all the proper capabilities I'm pretty sure. Here is the code for my data controller:

```
import CoreData
import Foundation

class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "TaskDataModel")
    
    init() {
        guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError("Container descriptions not loaded")
        }
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is TaskManMain:

```
@main
struct TaskManApp: App {
    @StateObject private var dataController = DataController()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the full repo if y'all are interested:
https://github.com/aabagdi/TaskMan

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you had the same issue as me, but I managed to find out my exact issue by a better error handling.

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "TaskDataModel")
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })

        return container
    }()
    
}
```

This gave me the exact error that was breaking my code. In my situation I had a Custom Constraint on one of my Entities and you can't use unique constraints with NSPersistentCloudKitContainer.
I finally managed to find a workaround by making a function .
Hope it helps!